# Phalcon Controller $this->session and Phalcon\Session\Manager()

Tags: phalcon

I'm using [Phalcon v.4](http://phalcon.io) and I have seen that are two ways to create the session inside a controller:

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function postAction(): Response
    {
      $session = new Phalcon\Session\Manager()
    }
}
```

or

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function postAction(): Response
    {
      $this->session;
    }
}
```

I have seen that the methods are the same, but I'm not able to understand the different and which is better to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you created your project using phalcon's cli devtools then the session service would be created by default in `app/config/services.php`

that being said in your controller when you access the instance's property `session` aka `$this->session` this would look for a service called `session` and by default it would setup session using file adapter and starts it and `$this->session` would return an instance of `Phalcon\Session\Manager`

Comment: I'm not able to understand which is the best that I have to use. I'm developing with phalcon's cli devtools in php.

Comment: use ```$this->session``` its already been set. ```$session = new Phalcon\Session\Manager()``` is doing the same thing again. take a look into ```app/config/services.php``` and you find its already been set. [also take a look at documentation](https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/di#registering-services)